# Formatting of sequential if statements with similar returns (C++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, if-statement

In my program, I use the map `map<name,labscores>` to store pairs of classes that store data about students and their grades. The overloaded `operator<` returns true if the mean of the first is lower than the second, but if they're equal, it then checks which has a smaller median, then which was a smaller name. The data_t class contains an iterator of the map which points to a specific pair.

```
bool operator<(const data_t &d){
    if(it->second.get_mean() < d.it->second.get_mean())
        return true;
    else if((it->second.get_mean() == d.it->second.get_mean()) && (it->second.get_median() < d.it->second.get_median()))
        return true;
    else if((it->second.get_mean() == d.it->second.get_mean()) && (it->second.get_median() == d.it->second.get_median()) && (it->first < d.it->first))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The above code works, but I'm trying to learn more efficient ways of coding, and I wanted to know if there was a simpler way of doing this or if there was a command that can help.

Comment: Usually if you have an `if` - `else if` chain where you are returning bools, you should collapse it all down to `return (cond) && (cond2) && ...` or something similar

Comment: How about: `return std::tie(it->second.get_mean(), it->second.get_median(), it->first) < std::tie(d.it->second.get_mean(), d.it->second.get_median(), d.it->first);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consider the `if ... return ... else` to be messy coding since the `else` is totally superfluous.

You can neaten up your code to be more readable by applying that guideline, and with some judicious variable usage, something like:

```
bool operator<(const data_t &d) {
    // Check means first.

    auto myMean = it->second.get_mean();
    auto otherMean = d.it->second.get_mean();
    if(myMean < otherMean) return true;
    if(myMean > otherMean) return false;

    // Means are equal, medians comes into play.

    auto myMedian = it->second.get_median();
    auto otherMedian = d.it->second.get_median();
    if (myMedian < otherMedian) return true;
    if (myMedian > otherMedian) return false;

    // Means and medians are equal, use the names.

    return (it->first < d.it->first);
}
```